# Will a Queue Storage message that is placed back in the queue always be placed in the front of the queue?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

The docs say for Azure Storage queues that:

> Messages in Storage queues are typically first-in-first-out, but
> sometimes they can be out of order; for example, when a message's
> visibility timeout duration expires (for example, as a result of a
> client application crashing during processing). When the visibility
> timeout expires, the message becomes visible again on the queue for
> another worker to dequeue it. At that point, the newly visible message
> might be placed in the queue (to be dequeued again) after a message
> that was originally enqueued after it.

I only allow my function app to scale to max 1 instance, so to me it sound like that if the function crashes, the message is placed back in the queue (in the front). And when it restarts it tries the same message, not the next one in the queue. So in this way I will be able guarantee ordering. Does this sound right?

I know I can guarantee ordering with Service Bus using sessions. But I'm trying to avoid it as I have to run this solution with VNETs and then I'll have to use the premium version which is pricey..

Comment: The part that you quoted clearly says, that a message that gets re-added to the queue (e.g. because your Function crashed), might be NOT added back to the front. So what is your remaining question?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the assumption it is alway put back in the front. I doubt it is now and things can always change. Also *typically first-in-first-out, but* tells me enough to be certain it is not the case.

Comment: Yeah I see, thanks. I'll try to add explicit handling in the code for ordering